# CSWP Query: How to concatenate a string to query variable {Site.URL}

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-search-web-part, sharepoint-search

I want to limit a query in a Content Search Web Part to just the Pages library of the current site (exclude any sub-sites).  Is there anyway to correctly concatenate "Pages" to the query variable {Site.URL}?

Here's what I've tried with no success (0 results returned):

```
path:{Site.URL}Pages

path:{Site.URL}/Pages/*

path:{Site.URL}/Pages
```

It only works when I hard code the path which I don't want to do:

```
path:"https://something.sharepoint.com/Pages"
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed to add "\" before the "S" in Site.URL.  Not sure why this is but I may investigate later.

```
{\Site.URL}/Pages
```